# How to filter admin list view for a given model dynamically in Django?

Tags: django, filter, django-admin

Goal: I want to achieve custom filtering in Django admin based on a model method result.

I am aware of the fact that SimpleListFilters need to override queryset method. I ended up doing a nasty hack:

---

```
class AverageSeverityAboveListFilter(admin.SimpleListFilter):
    title = 'Severity above'
    parameter_name = 'severity_above'

    def lookups(self, request, model_admin):
        severities = ProblemSeverity.objects.all()
        options = []

        for severity in severities:
            options.append((severity.level, severity.name))

        return options

    def queryset(self, request, queryset):
        pks = [problemset.pk for problemset in queryset
               if problemset.average_severity() < float(self.value())]

        for pk in pks:
            queryset = queryset.exclude(pk=pk)

        return queryset
```

---

I really do not want to introduce a new field to the model to cache the result, since this rank used to compare the model entries can be computed from the values already in the table and I am not a fan of data redundancy.

Assume a general case, that is average_severity() being complicated enough so that it cannot be expressed by a raw SQL query.

It works, but it's really ugly. Is there a better way?

Comment: You should paste the code of `average_severity()`.

Comment: I did that deliberately. Assume average_severity() is a general method and cannot be expressed by a raw SQL query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either add a field to cache the result of `average_severity()` in a [pre_save signal](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#pre-save) and use it in your queryset, either fall back to [raw sql](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/sql/).

Comment: I have evaluated both possibilities prior to asking the question. For complicated methods, that cannot be expressed by raw SQL, is there really no other option than introducing a new field to the model to cache the result?

Comment: You want to filter over a value server side, it's either python or sql.